# How to retrieve values from list and set a variable to value?

Tags: java

I have a List being created by a call to Utility for database calls.

```
List Details = DatabaseMgr.ValidateItemLocation(IsItem,isLevel,myArea,mLoc.getText().toString())
```

The following screen shot shows what detail returns.

I would like to set Strings to the AddNew, LocationType and Pass fields in the List. They all have values when the database call returns but I cannot figure out how to reference Details to use the values.
They are all values from outbound parameters from stored procedure.

Hope I explained myself. Java is still very new to me as I come from VB background.

Here is the screen shot

[image]

Comment: what is your question? Do you want to retrieve those values or you want to update?

Comment: Retrieve. I want to set String locType to "P"

Comment: but it's already set to "P" / next to that, dont use raw type, specify the type of the object in list : `List<ValidItemLocation>` and follow Java naming conventions :packages, attributes, variables, parameters, method have to start in lowerCase : `details`

Answer (score 2):

First, variables in Java must start with a lower case character. So rename `Details` as `details`.

It seems that `details` is an `ArrayList` containing `ValidItemLocation` objects, so you need to get the first item from the list and the you can use it. Use `get` to get something from a list.

```
ValidItemLocation item = (ValidItemLocation)(details.get(0));
System.out.println(item.AddNew); // example
item.locationType = "P";
```

The `(ValidItemLocation)` construct is called a cast and is used because you have not declared what the list is a list of, so Java just assumes it is a list of `Objects`. You could look into declaring details as a `List<ValidItemLocation>` type instead.

The next things you can do are to check that the list contains something before you access it (use `size()`) and rename all of your fields to start with lower-case letters.

If you think your list might contain more than one result item, then you need to iterate over it, as shown in some of the other answers.

Comment: Thank you. Knew it had to be something rather simple. Working now.

Answer (score 1):

Here I can see that you have `List<ValidItemLocation>` i.e. list of objects of class `ValidItemLocation` and `AddNew`, `LocationType` and `Pass` is it's member. So you can set the values just like below by iterating through it:

```
    for(ValidItemLocation validItemLocation : yourList)
    {
      validItemLocation.setAddNew("yourvalue");
      //same for other fields
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `for loop` to iterate over the items and get the fields, smth like

```
for (ValidItemLocation item : Details)
  String addNew = item.AddNew;
  System.out.println(addNew);
  ...
```